# PHP array, undefined index when looping

Tags: php, mysql, symfony

When I try to get timestamp index from an array,I get an undefined index error.

This is the multidimensional array in my page source

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [timestamp] => 14:58:25
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [timestamp] => 14:58:43
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [timestamp] => 14:58:54
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [timestamp] => 15:06:28
        )

)
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [timestamp] => 08:53:26
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [timestamp] => 09:19:42
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [timestamp] => 11:41:51
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [timestamp] => 11:44:01
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [timestamp] => 12:09:23
        )

)
```

And this is the code for my function:

```
private function getTimestamps ( $employee_id, $date )
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();       
    $sql = "SELECT TIME(time_record) as timestamp FROM log WHERE `employee_id` = '{$employee_id}' AND DATE(time_record) = '{$date}'";
    $stmt = $em->getConnection()->prepare($sql);        
    $stmt->execute();        
    $data = $stmt->fetchAll();        
    $output = array ();

    foreach ( $data as $d ) {
        $output[] = $d;
    }

    return $output;
}

public function indexAction()
{



    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();


    $sql = "SELECT e.id as employee_id,
                   e.firstname as firstname,
                   e.lastname as lastname,
                   DATE(l.time_record) AS requested_date
                   FROM employee e
                   INNER JOIN log l
                   ON l.employee_id = e.id
                   GROUP BY DATE(l.time_record), l.employee_id";


    $stmt = $em->getConnection()->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();
    $logs = $stmt->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    $timetracking = array ();

    foreach ( $logs as $log ) {

        $timetracking[$log['employee_id']][] = $this->getTimestamps ( $log['employee_id'], $log['requested_date'] );
    }


    foreach ( $timetracking[11] as $time ) {
        echo $time['timestamp'] . " ----- ";
        //print_r($time);
    }
    die ();
}
```

What am I doing wrong here? please help.

Comment: Post your entire **Warning** message. Undefined index of what? Which line? It will help us helping you. =)

Comment: I'm confused by `$timetracking[11]` - where does the hardcoded index number `11` come from?

Comment: $timetracking[11] is just for the test. i am trying to get all the timestamps for employee with ID 11.

ContextErrorException: Notice: Undefined index: timestamp in C:\xampp\htdocs\timeTracking\src\Backend\AdminBundle\Controller\LogController.php line 83

Comment: there's no sense of preparing if you're just going to directly inject variables in your query string.

Comment: aren't there supposed to be colons to separate each array elements?

Comment: yes , when i try to pass timetracking variable in view i still get the same errorr. 

<?php foreach ($logs as $log): ?>
   <tr>
    <td><?php echo $log['firstname'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo date("d/m/Y") ?></td>
    <?php foreach ( $timetracking[$log['employee_id']] as $next ): ?>
     <?php foreach ($next[0] as $time): ?>
      <td><?php echo $time['timestamp'] ?></td>
     <?php endforeach ?>
    <?php endforeach ?>
   </tr>
  <?php endforeach ?>

Comment: ok this is what i am trying to do in my view

<?php foreach ($logs as $log): ?>
   <tr>
    <td><?php echo $log['requested_date'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $log['firstname'] ?></td>
    <?php foreach ( $timetracking[$log['employee_id']] as $time ): ?>
     <td><?php echo $time['timestamp'] ?></td>
    <?php endforeach ?>
   </tr>
  <?php endforeach ?>

I still get undefined index timestamp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't get your goal and point but try:

```
foreach ( $timetracking[11][0] as $time ) {
        echo $time['timestamp'] . " ----- ";
        //print_r($time);
    }
```

According to your comment do you need this:

```
foreach ( $timetracking as $next ) {
echo '---NEXT---';
foreach ( $next[0] as $time ) {
        echo $time['timestamp'] . " ----- ";
        //print_r($time);
    }
}
```

**EDIT 3:**

or if I finally got your goals:

```
 foreach ( $logs as $log ) {

        $timetracking[$log['employee_id']] = $this->getTimestamps ( $log['employee_id'], $log['requested_date'] );
    }


    foreach ( $timetracking as $key=>$time ) {
        echo 'empoyee_id : '.$key. '; time '.$time['timestamp'] . " \n";
    }
```

**EDIT 4**
So you've sent in your comment (don't do it again, you should edit your original post and add edits to your question):

```
<?php foreach ($logs as $log): ?> 
<tr> <td><?php echo $log['firstname'] ?></td>
 <td><?php echo date("d/m/Y") ?></td> 
 <?php foreach ( $timetracking[$log['employee_id']] as $next ): ?> 
 <?php foreach ($next[0] as $time): ?> <td>
 <?php echo $time['timestamp'] ?></td>
  <?php endforeach ?>
```

this code is completely different form the last code I suggested!!

So again I just guessing what is your goal but if you prepared your arrays `logs` and `timetracking` the way I suggested then in **EDIT 3** you can try:

```
<?php foreach ($logs as $log): ?> 
  <tr> <td><?php echo $log['firstname'] ?></td>
  <td><?php echo date("d/m/Y") ?></td> 
  <?php foreach ( $timetracking[$log['employee_id']] as $key=>$time): ?> 
    <td> <?php echo $time['timestamp'] ?></td>
  <?php endforeach ?> </tr> 
<?php endforeach ?>
```

Comment: it fix the error but return only the first array. i mean the first part. my goal is to get all the time or timestamp for each employees(in this case just employee with id 11 to test it).

Array
(
    [timestamp] => 14:58:25
)
Array
(
    [timestamp] => 14:58:43
)
Array
(
    [timestamp] => 14:58:54
)
Array
(
    [timestamp] => 15:06:28
)

Comment: @chronos check update. and try to explain deeper and clearly your goals

Comment: The second suggested it works. i get all the timestamps for all employees. but when i try to pass an id for a given employee timetracking[11] it says ContextErrorException: Warning: Illegal string offset 'timestamp' in C:\xampp\htdocs\timeTracking\src\Backend\AdminBundle\Controller\LogController.php line 90

and i still get the same error undefined index with the last suggestion.

Comment: <?php foreach ($logs as $log): ?>
   <tr>
    <td><?php echo $log['firstname'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo date("d/m/Y") ?></td>
    <?php foreach ( $timetracking[$log['employee_id']] as $next ): ?>
     <?php foreach ($next[0] as $time): ?>
      <td><?php echo $time['timestamp'] ?></td>
     <?php endforeach ?>
    <?php endforeach ?>
   </tr>
  <?php endforeach ?>

when i am trying to loop in view

Comment: do you still need help?

Comment: Yes please. when i try to loop in view
<?php foreach ($logs as $log): ?>
   <tr>
    <td><?php echo $log['firstname'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo date("d/m/Y") ?></td>
    <?php foreach ( $timetracking[$log['employee_id']] as $next ): ?>
     <?php foreach ($next[0] as $time): ?>
      <td><?php echo $time['timestamp'] ?></td>
     <?php endforeach ?>
    <?php endforeach ?>
   </tr>
  <?php endforeach ?>

i get this error. 

ContextErrorException: Warning: Illegal string offset 'timestamp' in C:\xampp\htdocs\timeTracking\src\Backend\AdminBundle\Resources\views\Logs\index.html.php line 16

Comment: @chronos check my last update. you did completely different thing form what I was suggested.

Comment: Of course i tried but your last code still keeps showing the same error : undefined index timestamp.

Comment: POST your current code in your Question. If you did everything As I suggested - it must work

Comment: my whole point is to pass log['employee_id'] to timetracking

$timetracking[$log['employee_id']] , but when i do it still shows the error.

Comment: post your current code in your original post body, not here in comments if you need help